# google map search location center map issue in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I'm working on PHP, I have created address based google map from the database, in my website homepage has a search location autocomplete input type if I'm searching `(BTM layout Bangalore)` it is showing down position of a map I need current search location center position of the map please help someone.

**index.php**

```
<div class="form-group keyword">
    <input id="locationTextField" name= "area_name" type="text" size="50">   
    <button type="submit" name="filter"><img src="assets/images/search.png" alt="Rentozy" /></button>
</div>
```

Here maps script:pglist.php.

mysql query:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['area_name'])){
        $location_type =$_POST['area_name'];
        $arr = explode(' ',trim($location_type));
        $listing=$arr[0];
        $all_location ="select * from tbl_master_property where pg_address like '%$listing%'";
        $location_result=$conn->query($all_location);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($location_result)){
            //$location_result1[] = $row;
            $men_projects[] = $row;
            $locations[] = $row['pg_address'];
        }
    }
    $locations = json_encode($locations);
?>
```

**google map script:**

```
<div class="map">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBAM5Cs2VsrOBs8Idqy0t0o6vw4hEU0Lys"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var delay = 100;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
    }
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    function geocodeAddress(address, next) {
        geocoder.geocode({address:address}, function (results,status){
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var p = results[0].geometry.location;
                var lat=p.lat();
                var lng=p.lng();
                createMarker(address,lat,lng);
            }
            else {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                    nextAddress--;
                    delay++;
                } else {}
            next();
        });
    }
    function createMarker(add,lat,lng) {
        var contentString = add;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            draggable: true,
            map: map,
        });
        marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
        function toggleBounce() {
            if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
            } else {
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            }
        }
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
    }
    var locations = <?= $locations ?>;
    console.log(locations);
    var nextAddress = 0;
    function theNext() {
        if (nextAddress < locations.length) {
            setTimeout('geocodeAddress("'+locations[nextAddress]+'",theNext)', delay);
            nextAddress++;
        } else {
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }
    theNext();
</script>
```

Comment: please create a working fiddle. https://ideone.com/

Comment: i don't know how to create working fiddle

Comment: Can you describe what does work and what doesn't?